# Como obtengo un archivo.yml dentro de una carpeta? <JAVA>

Tags: java

Quiero saber como obtener una lista de archivos por ejemplo:

- MainFolder>

  - Arenas>

    1. Arena1.yml
    2. Arena2.yml

Y poder obtener los que contenga Arena1.yml.

Mi codigo (No funciona.):

```
    private static FileConfiguration arenas;
```

private void loadArena(){

```
    File folder = new File(getDataFolder()+"/arenas");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile()){
            if(listOfFiles[i] != null){
                String arena = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    new Arena(arena, arenas.getInt("maxplayers"),
                            arenas.getInt("minplayers"),
                            arenas.getString("sign").equals("NOEXIST") ? null : (Sign)unserializeLocation(arenas.getString("sign"))
                                    .getWorld().getBlockAt(unserializeLocation(arenas.getString("sign"))).getState(),
                            unserializeLocation(arenas.getString("mainLobby")),
                            unserializeLocation(arenas.getString("lobby")),
                            listStrToLocs(arenas.getStringList("spawns"))
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has intentado algo hasta ahora?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/luxacoxome.cs Esto es lo que intente pero me da error

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código del enlace. Y también di cual es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero este código para cargar el archivo y una vez que lo tengas en memoria puedes realizar todas las búsquedas necesarias

```
public void cargarArchivo(String direccion){
    lineas = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Path ruta = Paths.get(direccion);

        Stream<String> flujoFormateado = Files.lines(ruta, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // cargando el archivo plano
        flujoFormateado.forEach(lineas::add); // almacenando todos los elementos para su analisis

        System.out.println("lineas guardadas: "+lineas.size());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Archivo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```